# Changing Connections Properties of multiple Excel files using Text editors

Tags: sql-server, excel, text-editor

We have over 400 Excel files, that connect to a specific SQL server's databases. Currently we are undergoing an upgrade and the Server will change. The db names and tables will remain the same, so the only change in the connection property will be the server name.

I am looking for a quick way to do this using any text editor, and replacing the old name with the new one.

I've tried Notepad++ and EmEditor opening the .xls file as Binary (Hex view) and tried to replace the Hex equivalent of the ASCII characters with no success.

Also, I tried opening in non Binary view, but after saving many funtionalities of the excel are lost and I also get a message that the file is not a valid xls file.

Comment: Why do this with a text editor?

Comment: Just to avoid the process of opening 400+ excel files one by one and altering the string of the connection in every query they have.

Comment: You could use VBA to change the connection string.  See for example: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?49006-VBA-Change-ODBC-Connection-String-(Excel)

Comment: Is it possible to do this on all those files at one go?

Comment: You can use `Dir()` to loop over all of the files in a folder:

Comment: Thanks for the answers. However, I'd like to know if someone had a similar problem and solved it just by using text editors and replacing the string.

Comment: excel file is not text. How do you expect a text editor is able to edit that

Comment: I'm missing something? Sounds like you are trying to edit a packed *xls.  Is that right?  I would imagine your run into all sorts of fun problems that way.  Have you tried changing the extension to *.zip and opening that up?  You might find i the string you need to change conveniently sitting in the open for you.  If you do, it's a simple edit, save, zip it back up, rename the extension back to *.xls .... Times 400 +. Me?  I would run a macro in a windowless instance of excel l.  400 would files would be finished in less time than it took me to write this comment.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I am opening an xls file with text editors (mostly ones that support Hex encoding), searching for the server name i want to change, and replacing it. The replacement is successful, but obviously saving it afterwards, brings up many problems, as the excel loses data/functionalities (i've got all sort of errors). 

If I Zip the xls file, the connection .xml is editable but the process in 400+ is quite frustrating.  I'll check the macro solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It was successfully done by using UltraEdit, and replacing the string by selecting 'Replace in all files' and choosing the entire folder. So it seems that it can be done with a Text Editor, that doesn't open the file but instead it searches and replaces all instances of the string in a selected folder.

Thank you all for the contribution.